# Taking two steps and shooting the ball after being passed the ball without dribbling, is this condered a travel?

Tags: basketball

I was wondering, because I was playing basketball. They called a travel when I had been passed the ball and took two steps, then shot the basketball.

Comment: Yes 2 steps is traveling

Comment: It's not clear if you took the two steps from a stand still, or you were already running/moving when you got the ball

Answer (score 1):

Similar question answered here: [Traveling when catching the ball in motion of a layup?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15083/traveling-when-catching-the-ball-in-motion-of-a-layup)

To summarize, no it is not a travel. A player is allowed to catch the ball, take two steps and then shoot. You see this all the time in the NBA.

Other leagues have different rules, and so it's possible that there may be a league out there that does not permit this. During pickup games, it's possible that players will go by rules from various leagues instead of NBA rules. This can of course cause controversy as some players may be playing according to different rulebooks than others.

There is also some confusion as to what a travel is. You will see this during basketball games when all of the fans in the audience seem to be demanding a traveling call from the refs, but the player clearly did not travel.

So yes, the standard basketball move is that you are allowed to catch the ball, take 2 steps and then shoot.